# How do you run a Python script from within Notepad++ but using powershell and in the directory of the script?

Tags: python, powershell, notepad++

How do you run a Python script from within Notepad++ that opens in Windows Powershell and runs the script from the directory that the Python script is located even if there is a space in the directory path.

Comment: As an alternative, you might want to also check out the Notepad++ NppExec plugin available from the Plugin Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to run a Python script in Powershell you can press F5 to open the run dialog box, to run the python script in powershell normally you can use;

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"; python -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)""
```

This however opens up Powershell in an ugly format similar to what cmd looks like by default however it does have all the features, it also does not run the script from the directory so relative paths don't work. To make the Powershell look normal you should run it from the shortcut that is in the start menu, to allow it to work if the file path has a space in it you should put a \ before the quotation marks. The working run command is therefore;

```
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk" -noexit -command cd \"$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\"; python -i \"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)\"
```